# Convert C++ code (with pointers and bit shifting) to C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

I'm currently involved in a project to port C++ to C# code but some fragments are not that easy to port 1 to 1, like the following:

```
#define CMND_MOVEL              10
#define CMND_EXTRASIDE          0x80

char CmndBuffer[32];

int *dst;
dst = (int*) &CmndBuffer[0];

*dst = 0;
*dst |= (CMND_MOVEL + (Flags << 8));      
if (BoxSide) *dst |= CMND_EXTRASIDE;

dst++;
*dst = SequenceNr;
dst++;
*dst = 10 * LastDestination.x;
dst++;
*dst = 10 * LastDestination.y;
dst++;
*dst = 10 * LastDestination.z;
dst++;
*dst = Speed * 10;
dst++;
*dst = Accel * 10;    

result = ERR_COMMSOCK;
if (UdpCmdSocket >= 0)
{
    if (sendto(UdpCmdSocket, (const char*) CmndBuffer, 28, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&UdpCmdPeer, sizeof(UdpCmdPeer)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        // more logic here
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me in detail what is happening here? I know fairly well how pointers and bit shifting works but i'm not 100% sure whats happening here on byte level. What I see is that it is populating a data packet to throw it over UDP.

But far more important: how do I send this in C#?? (I will use the .NET Socket class)

I know it can be conceived as a lazy question but I thought maybe SO can help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming Speed etc are float quantities, I imagine the `Speed * 10`  lines are to preserve one decimal digit. the value of `CMND_MOVEL` being 10 may be to indicate this...or it could be something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code is probably assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4, which is not assured by the standard.  At any rate, it is using the first byte to hold the `CMND_MOVEL` and `CMD_EXTRASIDE` bits and the remaining 3 bytes to hold the value of `Flags`.  The layout is like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| Flags<<8      | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| CMD_MOVEL     | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| CMD_EXTRASIDE | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Each `char` in C/C++ is a single byte, corresponding to the `byte` type in C#.  The author wants to send values which are longer than this, so they are using an `int*` to write 4 bytes at a time.

This part:

```
//CmndBuffer[0] to zero
*dst = 0;
```

Actually sets to 0 `CmndBuffer[0]` through `CmdBuffer[3]`.  Since they increment the `dst` pointer six times, they end up writing up to `CmdBuffer[27]`.  The last four bytes seem to be left with uninitialized values.

If you wanted to write it byte-by-byte, you would need to use bit-shifting and masking.  Something like:

```
byte[] buffer = /*...*/;
int index = /*...*/;
int sequenceNr = /*...*/;

buffer[index] = (byte) (sequenceNr >> 24) & 0xFF;
buffer[++index] = (byte) (sequenceNr >> 16) & 0xFF;
buffer[++index] = (byte) (sequenceNr >> 8) & 0xFF;
buffer[++index] = (byte) sequenceNr & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 2):

I will try to add some comments for clarification

```
//some constants for later use
#define CMND_MOVEL              10
#define CMND_EXTRASIDE          0x80

char CmndBuffer[32];

int *dst;
//Load the address of the first element of CmndBuffer into dst;
dst = (int*) &CmndBuffer[0];

//CmndBuffer[0] to zero
*dst = 0;
//this loads (CMND_MOVEL + (Flags << 8) into dst. Flags << 8 means a multiplication with 2^8
*dst |= (CMND_MOVEL + (Flags << 8));      
if (BoxSide) *dst |= CMND_EXTRASIDE;

//go to the next array element. The same applies to the commands below
dst++;
//write the value into the current array element
*dst = SequenceNr;
dst++;
*dst = 10 * LastDestination.x;
dst++;
*dst = 10 * LastDestination.y;
dst++;
*dst = 10 * LastDestination.z;
dst++;
*dst = Speed * 10;
dst++;
*dst = Accel * 10;    

result = ERR_COMMSOCK;
if (UdpCmdSocket >= 0)
{
    if (sendto(UdpCmdSocket, (const char*) CmndBuffer, 28, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&UdpCmdPeer, sizeof(UdpCmdPeer)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        // more logic here
    }
}
```

as for the second part of your question have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/eae4f5y0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Lukas already covered most of it; but what it is effectively doing is moving along an array using pointer math. So this:

```
    dst++;
    *dst = 10 * LastDestination.x;
```

in C# would look like this

```
    var arrayIndex = 0;
    CmndBuffer[arrayIndex++] = 10 * LastDestination.x;
    CmndBuffer[arrayIndex++] = 10 * LastDestination.y;
```

and so on.